# intellij idea find by regex

Tags: intellij-idea

i need to search for initialization of classes by name, the project is big, and i want to use regex to find the instances inside the intellij idea . 
Here is a list of classes name:

1. BdService
2. BdClusterService
3. BdServiceClient
4. BdClusterServiceClient
5. BdServicesManager
6. BdServiceClientsManager

I need an advice and regexs also, but maybe you know the proper way to find the initialization of this classes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try *Find in Files* (`ctrl-shift-f`):

- tick "Regular expression"
- text to find: `Bd[a-zA-z]*Service`

Comment: `Bd.*Service` is simpler regex