How to search Chinese characters in IntelliJ IDEA?
Just search Chinese characters in IntelliJ IDEA, because I'd like to replace it with English characters in short time.  Is there a quick way to do this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547480/intellij-idea-find-by-regex & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-ascii-characters


Open global search dialog
Ctrl + Shift + F(Windows)
Command + Shift + F(MAC)

Type Regular Expressions and click the .* button
[\u4e00-\u9fa5] 

Search success!(Like the following picture)
search dialog


